# Simple WinForm with gridview app not responding

Tags: c#, winforms, sqldataadapter

I got a simple winform app, basically it just loads data from the DB into a gridview and displays it, in order to do it i'm using a DataAdapter, I have around 7000 rows to show, in my local computer (Win7) it works fine, in the server howerver (2008 server) it loads the data, shows at least the first screen (although it doesn't show the scrollbar on the right to scroll down) and then it goes to Not Responding.

Trying to find the problem, I made sure the .net framework 4.0 is installed

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[csName].ConnectionString;
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_getAllDocuments", con);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

I even tried printing any possible Exception to a label there, but since it goes to not responding nothing else happens.

When I cut down the results from 7000 to 4 then it works, any ideas?, the sever is a good computer.

Comment: I added a try catch block on the backgrounworker that was binding the gridview to the datatable with a simple throw; on the catch, expecting to see any errors but instead it just started working! so it is working now...

Comment: too long time to push the data on UI...

Comment: it actually doesnt take that long, it was taking 20 secs on my local, on the server it actually took 5 now that is working, but good to know that, how could I fix it in the case of being too long?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Timeout to 10 secs and try

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 10000;
```

May be the time out is the problem

Comment: No, the SelectCommand.CommandTimeout is acutally in seconds, that is the first thing I tried, 600 actually means 10 mins, (of course that is a way to high value for that, just wanted to make sure the problem was not a timeout), as commented above it already works adding a try catch block and a throw on the catch made it keep running, I suspect it was something to do with teh UI not updating, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it just takes longer in production environment... could that be it?
Have you considered using a `DataReader` instead of the `DataAdapter`? I think the DataReader will be better in your case

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931.aspx

Comment: you think so?, I use a datatable because the gridview then can get sorted and filtered with the filters the user adds on top of it, for any of the 9 columns (multiple filters), since the db is being used for another 10 users at the same time i just want to make sure i don't overload the DB each time they want to apply a filter etc.

Comment: I understand, but since you don't need to update data from the grid (right?) I would make a small test and try a `DataReader`